# %d format is required not str error in tkinter python to mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, tkinter, mysql-python

my entry widget

```
 e2 = Entry(f, width=20)
        e2.place(x=280,y=120)
```

i changed it into int type

```
 def add_data():
    roll=int(e2.get())
```

my query to insert data into MySQL

```
 cursor.execute('insert into first_year( name,roll_number,phone_no, MATH,English,science) values(%s,%d,%s,%s,%s,%s)',(name, roll, phone_no, math, Eng, sci))
```

error

```
%d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: Your `add_data` doesn't return or change anything. You might want to read more about `variable scope`.

Comment: my query and roll=int(e2.get()) are in same function

Comment: Just change %d with %s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the %d with %s (even for numbers), because placeholders are not regular Python as you can red [here](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples)

```
cursor.execute('''insert into first_year( name,roll_number,phone_no,
                MATH,English,science) values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',
                (name, roll, phone_no, math, Eng, sci))
```

Comment: won't that make user enter  string too wait lemme try